# Cordova geolocation works only when phone is on charge

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, geolocation, cordova-plugins

I'm actually developing an application with Cordova, Ionic and AngularJS.

I'm using the Cordova Geolocation plugin, this one works well when the phone is charging. But when I'm removing the cable, it's impossible to get the Speed, Longitude and Latitude anymore.

I'm using the plugin with HighAccuracy on false.

Any idea ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Coule be working may be beacuse of USB connection not cos of charging of course :)

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your answer. Any idea ?

Comment: It sounds really weird when you a functionality is working only while charging mobile. Are you using usb to charge by connecting it to computer? Post your code too